# Magento Freightquote Error: Source model "Freightquote_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Source_Class" not found for attribute "freightquote_class"

Tags: error, extensions

I installed the freightquote extension to try it out and didn't like it so I uninstalled it.

When I uninstalled this extension and go to edit a product I get a fatal error.

The error log is below.  Please help me this extension has broke my store.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:108:"Source model "Freightquote_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Source_Class" not found for attribute "freightquote_class"";i:1;s:3354:"#0 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "F...')
#1 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php(70): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)
#3 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#9 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#10 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#11 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#12 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#13 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#14 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(Array, true, true)
#15 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(250): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout(Array)
#16 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->editAction()
#17 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#18 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/shopcapa/public_html/store/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:89:"/store/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/2841/key/7dfbc8e46bf196fb9e645b8391e16c09/";s:11:"script_name";s:16:"/store/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: Please make sure you have cleared the cache after uninstalling the extension, also check that the compilation in magento is turned off.

Comment: I did clear the cache and checked that compilation was off.  Both are and I still can't access my products in the admin.  Is it possible this installed or overwrote some code somewhere it shouldn't of?  Then when it uninstalls in is not removing it.

Answer (score 2):

So the reason for this error is because the extension has installed at least one attribute with a custom source model. Unfortunately Magento does not have a nice deinstallation process for modules.

What I would recommend doing here is to create your own module with a simple set-up scrip that removes the attribute with the code `freightquote_class`.

You may also want to look into the uninstalled extension's code base to see if there was any more attribute either installed or edited by this extension and revert these changes via your own extension.